# jQuery qTip and FullCalendar with agendaWeek as view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, qtip

I am making a website that anyone can embed our calendar using iFrame. That calendar is using FullCalendar and qTip.

I am using FullCalendar with a default view of `agendaWeek`, the problem with that is when I click on an event the qtip appears, but when I scroll down, the qtip popup position is like `fixed`. It is very difficult to explain so here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uH4W/)

Here's my code:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  allDayDefault: false,
  allDaySlot: false,
  columnFormat:{
    week: 'ddd dS'
  },
  events:{
    url:"http://<?=$rootUrl;?>/studios/fetch_event_calendar_public/",
    data:{
      id:"<?=$studio_id;?>",
    }
  },
  eventRender: function(event,element,view){
   ... ... ... ..
    jQuery(element).qtip({ // Grab some elements to apply the tooltip to
      id: 'calendar',
      content: {
        text: html,
        button: 'Close',
        title: 'Event Details',
      },
      style: 'qtip-light',
      position: {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center'
      },
      show:{
        event:'click',
      },
      hide:{
        event: 'unfocus'
      },
    });
  },
  windowResize: function( view ) {
    calendar.fullCalendar('option', 'height', $(window).height() - 40);
  }
});
```

So what I want here is that when the fullcalendar is scrolled down or up, the qtip should not have a position of `fixed`, it should just stay where the event is.

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The qtip is absolute positioned. Maybe you could listen to the scroll event and update the qtip top manually?

Comment: @merlin that sounds like a good idea! Thanks for that! but also tricky though. Maybe there's a simpler way? I'll try that one :)

Comment: Seems qTip 1.0 is soon be obsolete. Why not take a look at qTip2, they have a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/N78hs/) showing how to integrate qTip2 into FullCalendar.

Comment: @merlin That is qTip2 :)

Comment: oops, just ignore my comment Orz..